# Is there a way to get dplyr's bind_cols to expand number of rows like in cbind?

Tags: r, dplyr

From `?dplyr::bind_cols`:

> This is an efficient implementation of the common pattern of do.call(rbind, dfs) or do.call(cbind, dfs) for binding many data frames into one

However, with example data:

```
tmp_df1 <- data.frame(a = 1)
tmp_df2 <- data.frame(b = c(-2, 2))
tmp_df3 <- data.frame(c = runif(10))
```

The command `do.call(cbind, list(tmp_df1, tmp_df2, tmp_df3))` produces:

```
   a  b         c
1  1 -2 0.8473307
2  1  2 0.8031552
3  1 -2 0.3057430
4  1  2 0.6344999
5  1 -2 0.7870753
6  1  2 0.9453199
7  1 -2 0.6642231
8  1  2 0.9708049
9  1 -2 0.7189576
10 1  2 0.9217087
```

That is, rows of `tmp_df1` and `tmp_df2` are recycled to match the number of rows in `tmp_df3`.

In `dplyr`:

```
> bind_cols(tmp_df1, tmp_df2, tmp_df3)
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  incompatible number of rows (2, expecting 1)
```

The reason why I want to do something like this is because I am in a situation similar to below:

```
df_normal_param <- df(mu = rnorm(10), sigma = runif(10))

df_normal_sample_list <- lapply(1:10, function(i) 
                         with(df_normal_param, 
                              data.frame(sam = rnorm(100, mu[i], sigma[i]))
```

and I wish to attach the arguments used to create each entry of `df_normal_sample_list` to the outputs, e.g.

```
df_normal_sample_list <- lapply(1:10, function(i) 
                         cbind(df_normal_param[i,], df_normal_sample_list[[i]]))
```

Comment: One of the examples explicitly states that it won't do what you want: `# Rows do need to match when column-binding
bind_cols(data.frame(x = 1), data.frame(y = 1:2))` so I would gather that it is an intentional design decision that will be difficulty to circumvent within dplyr.

Comment: `tidyr::fill()` is the closest I can think of for filling in missing values. Typically gluing database tables together based on a sort position gives *bad* results; have a feeling that is the reason for the safety tape.

Comment: In my case it is both safe, and desired. I have a function `f(x,y,z)` which produces a data frame with multiple rows. I have another data frame with columns x, y, z, such that each row of this data frame provides the arguments to the function `f`. I want to `cbind` the arguments used to create the output of `f` with the output of `f` to do some analysis later.

Answer (score 2):

You argue in a comment that this behavior is safe, I strongly disagree. It seems safe, for this very particular case, but it is likely to cause you problems somewhere down the road. Which is why I believe that the answer to your stated question ("Is there a way to get dplyr's bind_cols to expand number of rows like in cbind?") is a simple: no, and they probably built it that way intentionally.

Instead, I would suggest that you be more explicit in your approach, and just add the columns you want right as you build the data you are creating. For example, you could include that step right in your call (here using `apply` to clarify what is going where)

```
df <- data.frame(mu = rnorm(3), sigma = runif(3))

df_normal_sample_list <- apply(df, 1, function(x){
  data.frame(
    mu = x["mu"]
    , sigma = x["sigma"]
    , sam = rnorm(3, x["mu"], x["sigma"])
  )
})
```

Returns

```
[[1]]
          mu     sigma       sam
1 -0.6982395 0.1690402 -0.592286
2 -0.6982395 0.1690402 -0.516948
3 -0.6982395 0.1690402 -0.804366

[[2]]
         mu     sigma       sam
1 -1.698747 0.2597186 -1.830950
2 -1.698747 0.2597186 -2.087393
3 -1.698747 0.2597186 -1.961376

[[3]]
         mu     sigma       sam
1 0.9913492 0.3069877 0.9629801
2 0.9913492 0.3069877 1.2279697
3 0.9913492 0.3069877 1.1222780
```

Then, instead of binding the columns, then the rows, you can just bind the rows at the end (also from `dplyr`)

```
bind_rows(df_normal_sample_list)
```

Comment: And for the alternating values just filter all even rows `%2 == 0` before assigning the value in

Comment: Can you please give an example where you think this will give me problems down the road?

Comment: The most likely scenario is when your `df_normal_param` changes before you do the combining. This could happen if you change something, and forget to recreate `df_normal_sample_list` or if there is an error creating the new `df_normal_sample_list`, and you don't catch it, so accidentally merge to an old version. It is also very easy to miss a change in the creation of your output that changes something (e.g., number of rows per group). I've also run into substantial issues with functions that occasionally return NULL or NA -- depending on details, those are handled very differently by `cbind`